# how can i set the sound to louder than 100% on cinnamon

Tags: sound, cinnamon

I have installed cinnamon enviroment on ubuntu 16.04 and set the volume on louder than 100% but when i use the sound buttons on my key board it returns to 100%

Answer (score 2):

In Cinnamon install `Sound With Apps Volume` from the "add applets" menu and then add it to panel.
It has the option to allow turning the volume up to 150% without having to open sound settings.

Otherwise you should have this option in sound settings.

Comment: Please select it as an answered if it helped! Thx